# How to search data selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create a Advance search box for my site.I am using a "drop-down box" and a "text-box" to get the value to start my search in the site.

I want to search based on textbox value and dropdown value is "image" then click on search button..

In dropdown have two value

1. Image
2. Video

If select image then only image will display else only video will display.

ADSearchbox image URL

Thank You.

```js
$('#findNow').on('click',function(){
    document.getElementById("content11").innerHTML ="";
    document.getElementById("content12").innerHTML ="";
    var a =$('#search1').val();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOURAPIKEY&cx=005124428384360536924:rstfldysumw&q="+a+"&searchType=image&safe=high";
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function() {
        console.log("success");
    }).done(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
             var item = data.items[i];
             document.getElementById("content11").innerHTML += "<div class='col-md-3 c'>" + "<div class='b'><a class='add_img'><img src=" + item.link + " height="200px" class='thumbnail' width="200px" /></a></div><div class='a mn-video-title'> " + item.title + "</div></div>";
             document.getElementById("content12").innerHTML += "<a href='#_' class='lightbox' ><img src=" + item.link + " /></a>";
            $('.lightbox').each(function(i){
                var a = 'img' + (i++);
                $(this).attr('id',a);
            });
            $('.add_img').each(function(i){
                var b = '#img' + (i++);
                $(this).attr('href', b);
            });
        }
    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log("error");
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="log">
    <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 aa">
            <label class="co" for="usrname">Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here.." name="search" id="search1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 bb">
            <label class="co" for="psw">Select Category</label>
                <select name="category" id="sel" class="form-control">
                    <option value="image">Image</option>
                    <option value="vidio">Vidio</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="bbt">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect" name="sear">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```